# What umbrella word would apply for training, event, competition, besides event?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am working with a legacy software project that already uses events as a category of [insert umbrella word here].
In order to have clarity of naming variables and classes, it would be perfect if I could use another umbrella word other than event to describe all three types: training, event, competition.

Comment: Occasion, occurence, happening, feat, undertaking, affair, undertaking, hap, act, meeting, episode, get-together, item, doing, experience, case, fait.

Comment: None fit the context.

Comment: Even after all this time, the only words that spring to mind for "… training, event, competition…" are still your own "event" and Burhan Khalid's "activity," 

Why would they not work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about *activity*, as in `Select the type of activity:`, borrowing from this definition from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/activity):

> a form of organized, supervised, often extracurricular recreation The
>   camp offers hiking, swimming, and other activities.